# Symfony2 pages being served out as plain text

Tags: symfony

I apologise in advance if this question has an obvious solution that I'm not aware of.

My symfony2 app webpages are now being served out as plain text instead of HTML. This is happening on the webhost (production environment) and my localhost development environment.

The last four things I did were:

1. Downloaded/installed FOSRestBundle and JMS serializer and got it working with a couple of get requests
2. Changed the live and localhost environments to production, tested them, then changed localhost back to development environment
3. Changed a link to the css file in base.html.twig from being a mixture of uppercase/lowercase to all lowercase
4. Cleared the cache by running app/console cache:clear

I'm not sure which of these changes (if any of them) caused the app to stop working or why... And in both locations.

Comment: What do u mean by served as plain text? I guess some headers have been modified. Could u pls post ur request\response headers. Especialy Accept and Content-Type.
And yes, it's just a guess, but i assume ur point 1 messed whole thing up.

Comment: By plain text I mean I go to localhost/web/app_dev.php/something and I get this in the browser:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=UTF-8>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=utf-8" />
 <title> .. etc.

On the webserver the request/response headers I get are:
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json
vary: accept-encoding

Comment: As I can see from comments, ur system started to set response header's for browser, that data it recieve is application\json. So browser represents data as it was told by response. And it seems to me, that problem is in FOSRestBundle, as i told before.

Comment: As quick answer i would recommened u to dig through config (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration-reference.md). For full answer we need your config for that bundles, or(and) ur code.

Comment: The problem was in the app/config/config.yml. It was like this as per a tutorial I was following:

    fos_rest:
        format_listener:
            prefer_extension: false
            default_priorities:
                - json

I changed it to this according to FOSRestBundle docs:

    fos_rest:
        routing_loader:
            default_format: json

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the app/config/config.yml. It was like this as per a tutorial I was following:

```
fos_rest: 
    format_listener: 
        prefer_extension: false 
        default_priorities: 
            - json
```

I changed it to this according to FOSRestBundle docs:

```
fos_rest: 
    routing_loader: 
        default_format: json
```

Comment: Hope our comments helped u :)